# Extract JSON array in Redshift when the object name is a variable value

Tags: json, parsing, amazon-redshift

Apologies up front if I use incorrect terminology, I'm relatively new to JSON.  I'm querying data from Amazon Redshift.

The following is an example of the JSON data I'm seeing:

{"id":{"names":["name1", "name2", "name3"]

I want to get the object containing the names (of which there can be up to 15).  Normally this does the trick without a hitch:

select json_extract_path_text(column, 'id', 'names')

I'm hitting a snag in this case, however.  The "id" is a variable number...it's actually a customer ID number.  This means the ID is going to be different in every case, so one row might contain:

{"12345":{"names":["Lisa", "Dave", "Sean"]

while the next row might contain:

{"6789":{"names":["Phil", "Jenny"]

The JSON functions that Redshift supports aren't working out.  How can I get the "names" object when the path element is different every time?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Redshift User Defined Functions(UDFS). Easy, Simple to test & manage for such requirement. UDFs could be refined to support different params & details.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dynamic_json_extract_path_text (txt VARCHAR(20000) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(20000) IMMUTABLE AS $$
    import json
    try:
        data = json.loads(txt)
        for d in data:
            return json.dumps(data[d]['names'])
        return ''
    except:
        return ''
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```